# Threads to print series in Sync

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Java Threads these days and want to clear few basic doubts.
My aim is to have 3 threads each printing their respective jobs

Thread 1 will print series : 1 4 ...

Thread 2 will print series : 2 5 ...

Thread 3 will print series : 3 6 ...

1. I have wrote below code, and things are working fine but want to verify is my code correct??
2. Also, is `mapOfPrinter.wait()` is same as `synchronized (mapOfPrinter)`?
   I mean to say, calling `mapOfPrinter.wait()`, makes the current thread (ie one who has acquired monitor) to release the lock and go in waiting state. 
   Also, if any thread has acquired a lock then another thread who encounters 
   `synchronized (mapOfPrinter)` has to wait for lock to be released. In both cases, waiting is same or it differs?
3. If multiple threads are waiting for lock to be freed (mapOfPrinter here), then doing `mapOfPrinter.notify()` will awake which thread among waiting threads.
4. how we can awake only particular thread among the list of threads waiting on same mutex?

Let me know if I am not clear in explaining the question.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Printer> mapOfPrinter=new HashMap<String, Printer>();
        Printer p1 = new Printer(1, mapOfPrinter);
        Printer p2 = new Printer(2, mapOfPrinter);
        Printer p3 = new Printer(3, mapOfPrinter);

        Thread t1 =new Thread(p1, "1");
        Thread t2 =new Thread(p2, "2");
        Thread t3 =new Thread(p3, "3");

        mapOfPrinter.put("1", p1);
        mapOfPrinter.put("2", p2);
        mapOfPrinter.put("3", p3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }

}

class Printer implements Runnable{
    int data;
    Map<String, Printer> mapOfPrinter;
    static volatile int seriesToPrint=1;

    public Printer(int data, Map<String, Printer> mapOfPrinter) {
        this.data=data;
        this.mapOfPrinter=mapOfPrinter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true){
            synchronized (mapOfPrinter) {

                if(seriesToPrint>mapOfPrinter.size()){
                    seriesToPrint=1;
                }

                Thread currThread = Thread.currentThread();

                if(!(currThread.getName().equals(String.valueOf(seriesToPrint)))){
                    mapOfPrinter.notifyAll();
                    try {
                        mapOfPrinter.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    Printer p = mapOfPrinter.get(String.valueOf(seriesToPrint));
                    System.out.println("Thread"+ currThread.getName() + " = " + p.data + " ");
                    p.data=p.data+3;
                    seriesToPrint++;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }   
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand mentality of people who give negative votes. you are genius and not all. is this question really be given negative vote???

Answer (score 0):

1. Verifying your code is correct is a wide and difficult subject. You can get startet with testing it, and then do more testing. This will give you a confidence that your code works, but will never tell you if it is really correct. The other way to go is to do a formal verification, but this is difficult and time consuming.
2. xxx.wait() is totally different from synchronized(xxx) {}. Using synchronized, you make sure only a single thread at a time can enter specific regions of code. xxx.wait() makes the current thread wait until some other thread calls xxx.notify(). As you seem to have missed something fundamental here, I'd suggest digging through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html
3. notify() will wake up one random thread.
4. afaik this is not possible. You could however use a different lock for each thread, and use the respective lock.

Comment: I don't agree with you that verifying code is very difficult. this is not a big project for you to verify .. formal verification is did later only I posted code. if you read my question correctly, I clearly mentioned, is waiting stuff or better waiting properties common in both the case as both makes thread in waiting state.